# How to implement an infinite image loop?

Tags: java, image, awt, paint, infinite

I am currently working on a 2D shooter with moving background. The background is just a simple image. I want to implement that the image is moving endless from top to bottom.

I thought about determining the part of the image that is at the bottom outside the visible part of the frame and paint it on the top again.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics go) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) go;

    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    g.drawImage(this.imgBackground, 0, this.yBackground, this);
}
```

yBackground is the coordinate where the upper left corner of the image is drawn. It is altered from another thread:

```
while (!this.paused) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int y = this.display.getBackgroundY();

    if (y == this.display.getHeight()) {
        y = 0;
    } else {
        y++;
    }
    this.display.setBackgroundY(y);
}
```

So here is my question: how can I get the part of the image this is outside the visible part of the frame?

Comment: 1. please why??? 2. don't to use public void paint(Graphics go) {, search for paintComponent, 3. don't block EDT by Thread.sleep(10);, use Swing Timer instead 4. sleep(10); is very quick pause, touched latency of Native OS, starting with => 33 without own RepaintManager, etc... and for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you might be able to achieve this, but the basic premise is, you need some kind of scroll offset that determines the start of the basic image.

You then need to fill in the area before and after it (in case the image is smaller then the available height) until the space is filled.

The following example uses a `javax.swing.Timer` to update a offset by a given amount.  The `paintComponent` method then renders all the space before and after it, including the current image position.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ScrollingBackground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ScrollingBackground();
    }

    public ScrollingBackground() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new BackgroundPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage bg;
        private int yOffset = 0;
        private int yDelta = 4;

        public BackgroundPane() {
            try {
                bg = ImageIO.read(new File("Background.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    yOffset += yDelta;
                    if (yOffset > getHeight()) {
                        yOffset = 0;
                    }
                    repaint();;
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return bg == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (bg != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

                int xPos = (getWidth() - bg.getWidth()) / 2;
                int yPos = yOffset;

                while (yPos > 0) {
                    yPos -= bg.getHeight();
                    g2d.drawImage(bg, xPos, yPos, this);
                }

                yPos = yOffset;
                while (yPos < getHeight()) {
                    g2d.drawImage(bg, xPos, yPos, this);
                    yPos += bg.getHeight();
                }

                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might be able to optimism this by using a backing buffer and or subImage, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 1):

You can just draw the image again starting at height `yBackground + imgBackground.getHeight()`. The extra extending above the view gets clipped off, just like the bottom is clipped off in your code already.