# Java: Drawing grid to screen using 2D Array without lag/screen flickering

Tags: java, arrays, performance, graphics, conceptual

I am attempting to create a very simple top-down game in Java, but I am unsure how to approach a problem dealing with program performance.

I used a 2D array to store certain values that represent certain things, such as the surrounding environment and the player's position. I then used the paint() method to draw a grid to the screen based on a section of the 2D array. The player is always in the center of the grid. I have it coded such that the player never truly "moves", but rather the environment around him "moves" (if you press a key to move up, a new section of the array is drawn that is the same as the past section except it has a new row at the top and the bottom-most row is now the past section's second-to-bottom row, all the while the player stays in the center, if that makes sense).

Thus, we have a situation where the whole screen needs to be redrawn each time the player moves. As you might have gathered, this is bad for the program's performance, since it has to iterate through a 2D array and draw it the screen each time I call repaint(). If the user hits the key to move upwards twice in succession, the program will lag and the screen will flicker as it redraws the whole section of the array.

How can I improve the performance issue, given that I want to keep the player in the center of the screen at all times and have the environment move around him? Should I instead investigate Jscrollpanes? Is iterating through arrays in the paint() method not the way to go?

Thank you so much for both your time and also helping an inexperienced programmer.

Comment: *"Thus, we have a situation where the whole screen needs to be redrawn each time the player moves"* - Cache the background - use a `BufferedImage` and simply either offset the location of the image or generate a `subImage` which can be drawn within the available viewable space

Comment: In .NET it is possible to copy a raw pixel array to a memory bitmap for efficient blitting, using `System.Marshal`. Don't know if there is an equivalent in Java.

Comment: Unless your 2D array is very large (just as a guess, maybe 1000x1000), I doubt that any performance issues you're seeing are due solely to the painting. It's more likely that you're doing something like reading files inside of `paint` which is the primary cause of the performance issues. Also, we can't really offer much help without a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to look through.

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011545/how-to-implement-an-infinite-image-loop/18011851#18011851)

Comment: [And example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050723/java-applet-game-2d-window-scrolling/16052048#16052048) - as to your comment - no, not really.  You can affect the state of a `BufferedImage` in a "similar" way, but you'd have to do some trial and error to see how affective it is

Comment: Have a look at [`WritableRaster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) which you can get from `BufferedImage`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks! I will definitely look into what you have posted.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thank you for your comment! I'm not sure either, I'll look into it