# How can I make an object move from left to right slowly

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make an object, the ground, move from the left of the screen to the right slowly, using a for loop and a timer. The only measure of success I have achieved is getting the ground to move, but it immediately teleports away as soon as the application is started. I have looked into threads and thread.sleep to slow it down, but now I am faced with a white screen, and cannot see my visuals at all. Am I using the thread incorrectly, or is the for loop not being used correctly? Please help. Thanks, here is the code, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Sam.K
 */


public class game extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private PaintSurface canvas;
    int x_position = 0;
    int y_position = 580;
    int x_speed = 7;
int velX= 20;

    /**
     * Creates new form game
     */
    public game() {
        this.setTitle("Bouncing Ball");
        this.setSize(1200, 650);
        // super.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(new PaintSurface(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setVisible(true);
        canvas = new PaintSurface();
        this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);




        //settings for the form, hyandling things such as exiting and size
        Timer timer = new Timer(50, e -> {
            canvas.repaint();
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
        class PaintSurface extends JComponent {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

     Rectangle2D background = new Rectangle2D.Float(0,0,1200,650);
     g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
     g2.fill(background);

      Rectangle2D ground = new Rectangle2D.Float(x_position,y_position,1200,30);
     g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
     g2.fill(ground);
    movement();
     g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
    }


        public void movement(){
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i = i + 1) {
                x_position = x_position +10;
                repaint();
                System.out.println("X-POS = " + i);
                 try { Thread.sleep(50); }   /* this will pause for 50 milliseconds */
                 catch (InterruptedException e) { System.err.println("sleep exception"); }
            }

        }
        }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(game.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(game.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(game.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(game.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new game().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: The timer acts as a pseudo loop, each time it fires, you update the state (change the delta) and schedule a repaint. I’d remove the loop and use the movement method just to update the x_position, calling it from the Timer, and lose the Thread.sleep

Answer (score -1):

Change your `movement` method to simply update the delta

```
public void movement(){
            x_position = x_position +10;
}
```

Remove the call to `movement` from your `paintComponent` method

Update you `Timer` to call the `movement` method

```
Timer timer = new Timer(50, e -> {
        canvas.movement();
        canvas.repaint();
 });
```

> and what about the if statements where if the version goes off the screen it goes back to the start? would i have to make a separate method for checking? and if so, would i call it in the graphics or in the timer? Thanks

You keep asking this question and you keep getting the same answer, I'm not sure what you expect to change.

I'd consider using something like [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011545/how-to-implement-an-infinite-image-loop/18011851#18011851) which simply paints the "overflow" of the image to fill the remaining space or [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138363/infinite-background-for-game/16138735#16138735) or even [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050723/java-applet-game-2d-window-scrolling/16052048#16052048) which uses `BufferedImage#getSubImage`, which is probably more efficient.

Based on the first two examples, you could also do something like...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BufferedImage background = new BufferedImage(800, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D g2d = background.createGraphics();
                g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 200);
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 800, 200);
                g2d.drawLine(0, 200, 800, 0);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new RenderPane(background));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class RenderPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage bgMaster;
        private BufferedImage bgImage;
        private Timer timer;

        private double delta = 1.0;
        private double backgroundXPos = 0;

        public RenderPane(BufferedImage background) {
            this.bgMaster = background;
            bgImage = new BufferedImage(getPreferredSize().width, getPreferredSize().height, bgMaster.getType());
            renderBackground();
            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    backgroundXPos -= delta;
                    if (backgroundXPos + background.getWidth() < 0) {
                        System.out.println("Reset");
                        backgroundXPos = 0;
                    }
                    renderBackground();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void renderBackground() {
            Graphics2D g2d = bgImage.createGraphics();
            g2d.drawImage(bgMaster, (int)backgroundXPos, 0, null);

            double overflow = bgMaster.getWidth() - (backgroundXPos * -1) - getWidth();
            if (overflow < 0) {
                double overflowX = getWidth() + overflow;
                g2d.drawImage(bgMaster, (int)overflowX, 0, null);
            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (bgImage != null) {
                g2d.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: and what about the if statements where if the version goes off the screen it goes back to the start? would i have to make a separate method for checking? and if so, would i call it in the graphics or in the timer? Thanks

Comment: I did what you suggested and it moves much more smoothly now, but the issue of repeating is still there.

Comment: Okay, you got it moving, now, in your movement method, you need to make some determinations about when to paint the image twice (so you get that overlap), in your past questions I’ve posted links two at least two other examples which demonstrate the concept - I’m not near a computer so I can’t post more

Comment: What do you mean by the overlap? I set it so when yhe version gets to the end (1200) then it sets the x position to 0. And when the second version whoch starts at -1200 gets to 1200 it goes back to -1200. Do you think this is wrong coordinates? Thanks

Comment: Overlap, where you need to stitch the start of the image to the end of the image - so it looks like it continues

Comment: @SamK I've updated the answer, you know have 4 runnable examples which could be used to solve your problem.  Remember, you are not going to find any one answer which answers your questions entirely, you will need to make some effort to understand the solutions and incorporate them into your design/solution

Comment: I'd be curious to know why this might attract a downvote? I what ways does it not answer the question? In what ways could it be improved? Since no new solutions have been provided I can only guess that either you don't understand the question or the answer